# How to get count of each column data

Tags: mysql, query

I am trying the fetch the data of the each user of each month. The table looks like below

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| user         |  pm_jan      |       actual_jan    |       pm_feb  | actual_feb |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   u1         |  w5           |     6               |   0           |    0       |
|   u2         |  w2           |     5               |   0           |    0       |
|   u3         |  w6           |     2               |   w7          |    7       |
|   u4         |   0           |     0               |   w6          |    2       |
|   u5         |   0           |     0               |   w2          |    3       |
```

In the above table now I want to fetch the total count of  pm and actual data of each month until december.

I tried the below but I am able to fetch only the count of jan month but I need it for every month count

```
    SELECT COUNT(pm_jan),COUNT(actual_jan) 
    FROM pm
    WHERE  pm_jan<>'' AND actual_jan<>''
```

What is the best query to approach this method

Comment: I'd recommend you to normalize your data into `(user, month, pm, actual)` structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(pm_jan > 0) count_pm_jan, 
       SUM(actual_jan > 0) count_actual_jan, 
       SUM(pm_feb > 0) count_pm_feb, 
       SUM(actual_feb > 0) count_actual_feb
FROM pm
```

Comment: I am getting the count of the actual but no the getting the count of pm because it is declared as varchar and contains text as `week1` like

Comment: @venkatesh Replace `> 0` condition with proper non-equiation with proper string literal (emply string or something else - for example, `SUM(pm_jan != '')`) or proper template checking operator (for example, `SUM(pm_jan LIKE "week%")`).

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT(x)` is the number of rows where `x IS NOT NULL`.
`COUNT(DISTINCT x)` is the number of different values of `x`.
`COUNT(*)` is the number of rows, and what you should say unless you specifically want of the above.